# How to Sort Python Objects

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have a nested list which contains different objects, they're duplicate pairs of objects in the nested list and i'm trying to remove them but i keep getting a

`TypeError: unorderable types: practice() < practice()`

I know this error is caused by me trying to work with objects rather than integers but i don't know how else to remove the duplicates here is what i tried

```
class practice:
    id = None

    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id

a = practice('a')
b = practice('b')
c = practice('c')
d = practice('d')
e = practice('e')
f = practice('f')

x = [[a,b],[c,d],[a,b],[e,f],[a,b]]

unique_list = list()
for item in x:
    if sorted(item) not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(sorted(item))

print(unique_list)
```

Comment: Pass in a comparator `key` to `sorted` should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to compare the objects by the id:

```
class practice:
    id = None

    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return other.id > self.id

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.id > other.id

unique_list = list()
for item in x:
    if sorted(item) not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(sorted(item))

print(unique_list)
[[<__main__.practice object at 0x7fe87e717c88>, <__main__.practice object at 0x7fe87e717cc0>],
 [<__main__.practice object at 0x7fe86f5f79e8>, <__main__.practice object at 0x7fe86f589278>],
 [<__main__.practice object at 0x7fe86f589be0>, <__main__.practice object at 0x7fe86f589c18>]]
```

Depending on the functionality you want to implement all the [rich comparison ordering methods](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization)  you can  use [functools.total_ordering](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering), you just need to define one of the methods and it will take care of the rest

```
from functools import total_ordering
@total_ordering
class practice:
    id = None

    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return other.id > self.id

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id == other.id
```

> Given a class defining one or more rich comparison ordering methods, this class decorator supplies the rest. This simplifies the effort involved in specifying all of the possible rich comparison operations:
>
> The class must define one of `__lt__()`, `__le__()`, `__gt__()`, or `__ge__()`. In addition, the class should supply an `__eq__()` method.

Comment: No prob, I just added the second example as it may help if you want to add more functionality later

Answer (score 3):

To support sorting without explicit keys for objects in Python 3, you must implement the `__lt__` special method:

```
class practice:
    id = None

    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.id < other.id
```

If you want the other operators to work, you'll have to implement their special methods as well, but for sorting `__lt__` is all you need.

As noted in the comments, the other way to do it is to provide an explicit key function to the `sorted` built-in:

```
sorted(item, key=lambda x: x.id)
```

Comment: was trying to use the lambda method, i created a new variable and equated it to sorted(item, key=lambda x: x.id) but when i try to print out the value, i get practice object is not iterable. isn't it supposed to be a list?

Comment: @danidee The first argument to sorted has to be an iterable of practice objects. So try `sorted([practice('b'), practice('a')], key=lambda x: x.id)` for example. It will return a new list in the form: `[practice('a'), practice('b')]`